# Division by zero - php modulus with numbers less than one

Tags: php

Can someone explain why I am getting error `Division by zero` when I want to use modulus operator and the second number is less than one (but more than 0 of course)

when I try

```
$a = 5
$b = 3
var_dump($a % $b);die; // result is as expected int(2)
```

but when I try this

```
$a = 5
$b = 0.5
var_dump($a % $b);die; // result is 

Warning: Division by zero
bool(false)
```

PHP 5.4.4, debian 7

thanks

Comment: Probably because modulo works only for integers and php is rounding 0.5 to 0, I'm not 100% sure though.

Comment: What Ende Neu said. If you change it to `$a / $b` you get `10` as expected. Modulus is for integers, it makes no sense otherwise.

Comment: @EndeNeu, thanks for the comment, seems you are right: just found in docs `Operands of modulus are converted to integers (by stripping the decimal part) before processing.`

Comment: Yep, I guessed that, I could't find proof though.

Comment: @Jonathon "*Modulus is for integers, it makes no sense otherwise*" modulus is most often used for integers in programming, but as a mathematical concept, it's perfectly valid to apply it to any real number. Many other languages support this, e.g. C# `5 % 1.3` → `1.1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The modulo operator discards the fractional part of it's operands. From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

> Operands of modulus are converted to integers (by stripping the decimal part) before processing.

This can be observed with the following:

```
$a = 5;
$b = 3.6;
var_dump($a % $b);die; // int(2)
```

To avoid this behavior, use the [`fmod`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) method instead:

```
$a = 5;
$b = 0.5;
var_dump(fmod($a, $b));die; // float(0)
```