# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError in working by %?

Tags: php, math, division

I'm testing below simple code in PHP:

`<?php

```
echo 5 % 0.75;
```

?>`

And I see error division by zero whereas 0.75 is not zero!?
what happens exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Division by zero - php modulus with numbers less than one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408825/division-by-zero-php-modulus-with-numbers-less-than-one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operator % is for int type and 0.75 is float. So PHP changes it to zero first :

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

If you want to work with float type you need to do :

fmod(5,0.75);

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php